# Unpacking elements in python

Tags: python, list, function, sum, unpack

After seeing an example as below:

```
def sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head + sum(tail) if tail else head
```

I wonder if I can change it to print head and sum of rests separately, so I changed it to be:

```
def sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head, sum(tail) if tail else head
```

However, when I test it, it returned to these results:

```
sum([1,2,3])
(1, (2, (3, 3)))
```

instead of

```
(1,5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be defining your own function named `sum`, because it hides the built in function with the same name.  Do you mean to be calling your own `sum` function recursively, or do you think that the built-in `sum` will be called inside your `sum` function?

Comment: Why do you *expect* `return head, sum(tail) if tail else head` to *sum* anything? You never add anything. You removed the addition

Comment: Again...just to let us all be clear on what you were thinking...do you mean to be calling your own function recursively, or are you wanting to call the built-in `sum` function inside your own `sum` function?  Either way of going at this is valid.  What were you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: Right, I think my problem was I didn't notice function was called inside the function. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

That's because you create a tuple with the head and tail for ***each*** recursion. You seem to only want to separate them the first time, not every time. I'd create two functions, one to separate the header and tail, and one to recurse:

```
def sum_items(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head + sum_items(tail) if tail else head

def split_and_sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head, sum_items(tail) if tail else head

split_and_sum([1,2,3])  # Returns (1, 5)
```

The reason for recursion is to apply the same logic over and over on a different set of data. But since you want to do two different things, it's best to simply have to different functions.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are using the `sum` builtin function, but that won't be accessible because your function is named `sum`, so if you change your function name it will work.

So try changing this line:

```
def sum(items):
```

To:

```
def func(items):
```

And when calling the function, change:

```
sum([1,2,3])
```

To:

```
func([1,2,3])
```

Then the result would be:

```
(1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've named your function `sum`, which overrides the built-in `sum` function.  But then you apparently want to call the built-in `sum` function inside your own `sum` function.  That doesn't work.  What you're doing is recursively calling your own function instead of calling the built-in `sum`.

Just rename your function, and you'll get the result you expect:

```
def my_sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head, sum(tail) if tail else head

x = my_sum([1,2,3])

print(x)
```

Result:

```
(1, 5)
```